# Reboot and relaunch a script if error

Tags: shell-script, gnu-screen, reboot, exit-status, job-control

I have a script (not written by me, I cannot modify it) that has to run for days, that sometimes fails (exits with an error).

In this case all I have to do is just **reboot** the server (there is no better solution for now), and **restart** the script. Currently I do this:

- log in via SSH
- `screen -S job`
- `./myscript.sh` to start the job (let's say this script contains just: `dothis` and this process might exit with an error)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to detach from screen
- ...wait a few hours...
- log in, resume the screen with `screen -r job`.

  If still running, detach and come back later.
  If the script has failed, `sudo reboot`, and start at step 1, to make the long job continue.

How to do this without manual intervention?

**How to automate this and have the server reboot automatically if the script exists with an error, and then restart the script?**

Comment: Why do you need to reboot server, why don't just restart the script itself?

Comment: We have tried (and failed until now) to debug the core problem (probably linked with software + hardware, but out of topic here). I noticed it doesn't work when simply relaunching the script *without* a reboot. Since I need to have this script run these next days (and I won't have time to solve the root problem soon), I'm looking for the solution described in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would try to put that script in a container. this would remove some dependencies from the host itself, and allow automatic restart.

**Solution using docker and docker-compose**

This approach requires docker and docker compose. If you have Ubuntu, you can istall them via `sudo apt install docker.io docker-compose`.

1. Create a Dockerfile to build your container, like:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY /path/to/script/on/host /myscript.sh
# maybe deal with some dependencies here
CMD /bin/bash /myscript.sh
```

Save the above named as `Dockerfile` in any folder. You can see some docs at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

2. Create a docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  scriptrunner:
    build: .
    restart: always
```

Place this as `docker-compose.yml` in **the same directory** as your Dockerfile. See some docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

I assume you want to get some output of the script, in which case you may have to set up docker volumes to "share" folders between your host and the container.

3. Go to your folder in a terminal and type `docker-compose up -d`.

Using this method, you put your script in a container, will restart the container after every script fail, and will run as a daemon.

**Solution using systemd**

If you don't want to deal with containers, you can wrap your script in another one, e. g. `my-runner.sh`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/my-script.sh || systemctl reboot
```

This will reboot your computer after the script fail. Note that rebooting may require a different command or root privileges.

And now, let's make a systemd service of our runner script. [This](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6) is a good tutorial but it comes down to the following:

Create a systemd unit file like `/etc/systemd/system/my-script.service` and put the following into it.

```
[Unit]
Description=my script runner service
After=network.target
Type=simple
User=my-user
ExecStart=/path/to/the/previous/my-runner.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now you only have to issue `systemcl start my-script && systemctl enable my-script` to start it and make it start after reboot.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this. Are we sure that there will be no reboot if command1 finishes successfully with `command1 || systemctl reboot`?

Comment: In the service file, you have `StartLimitIntervalSec=0[Service]` which is probably a typo? PS: can you add details why the StartLimitIntervalSec option, and why the RestartSec=1 option?

Comment: Reboot: if command1 finishes successfully and returns 0, the second command will not run.

Comment: Service file: I just copied it from the tutorial. I think you won't even need that line, I'll edit it out. I'm also removing the restart options because those are handled by the reboot itself