# Command to reset the system to a state as close as possible to the state after a reboot?

Tags: grub, reboot, bios, init

**Which commands should I run in a Linux / Ubuntu server to reset the currently-running system to a state as close as possible to the state after a reboot?** (without actually rebooting!)

I can imagine this should involve:

- flush IO disk operations
- empty all kinds of cache (disk / RAM)
- unmount all drives and remount them, including `/`, is this possible?
- kill all processes except `init`?

TL;DR: how to reboot (to reset the system memory etc.), without actually rebooting via BIOS sequence and GRUB?

I'm using a Ubuntu 18.04 using `systemd`.

---

Context: I have a complex script running for days, involving CPU / GPU computation, etc.
It sometimes fails in the middle with an error that I've been unable to debug up to now: I don't know if it comes from a faulty RAM, faulty GPU, maybe too high temperature, or another problem only software-related. The problem is not easily reproducible.

But one thing is sure:

- if I restart the script after it has failed, the same problem appears.
- if I first **reboot the computer** and then restart the script, then it works well (until the next failure a few hours or days later).

Thus I want to find a way to reset the currently-running system to a state as close as possible to the state after a reboot (thus this question). Or be able to automate the reboot (see [Reboot and relaunch a script if error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677191/reboot-and-relaunch-a-script-if-error)).

script

Answer (score 1):

The following command is the closest command to your need :

`telinit 1`

But to flush cache disk, you should use `sync`

Comment: This will set the system into rescue mode - I don't think OP boots to runlevel 1. They should probably return to their intended runlevel afterwards

Comment: Runlevel 1 is the closest state after a reboot. The OP didn’t say he want the system to do something like a soft reboot (reboot anything except the kernel).

Comment: @Panki What should I do after `telinit 1` to return to the normal runlevel?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer How to do a soft reboot (reboot anything except the kernel)?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer Also, does this clear the RAM cache etc. ? so we get with `free` a state very close to the state of `free` after reboot?

Comment: No, the this won’t go so far.

Comment: `telinit 5` should restore a normal state of the OS. I don’t think there is something like reboot anything except the kernel (`telinit 1`, and afterward `telinit 5` should be the closer). It won’t reset hardware stuff however.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is entirely possible

if the problem is gpu-based, then an unload and reload of the graphics-card module may help.
useful commands: `modprobe` `rmmod` `insmod`

if you have an additional onboard graphics card this should be possible during run-time

for debugging:
if the problem is hardware-related, check the system-logfiles

```
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/syslog
```

check the `dmesg` command

hth

Comment: I know it's not 100% possible (for a real reboot, one need a real reboot :)), but what's the closest thing to a reset into a state similar to after-reboot, from command line?

Comment: the thing is, according to your description the hardware is maybe in a faulty state. the best thing to reset the hardware is to reboot the machine. the second-best thing is to reload the drivers/kernel-modules

Comment: @basj some GPU-drivers are infamous for their low quality. So my first idea is to relaod that driver and see if it helps. It helps at least with my nvidia card from time to time...

Comment: How would you unload/reload the nvidia GPU driver, can you add this in your answer, it would be interesting for future reference. Thanks!